# centOS 6.7 - install imagick php

Tags: php, centos6, imagick

trying to install imagick extension for php (here is the env):

```
[root@localhost src]# cat /etc/*release*
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
cpe:/o:centos:linux:6:GA

[root@localhost src]# php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2015 17:39:00) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

---------------

[root@localhost src]# pecl install imagick
downloading imagick-3.3.0.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.3.0.tgz (179,978 bytes)
.................done: 179,978 bytes
17 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
Please provide the prefix of Imagemagick installation [autodetect] : 
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-armandPkqjM8/imagick-3.3.0
running: /var/tmp/imagick/configure --with-imagick

.....
```

-- I'm getting this error in the end... Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

```
/var/tmp/imagick/imagick.c:3299: error: ‘ZEND_MOD_END’ undeclared here (not in a function)
make: *** [imagick.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: note that php 5.3.3. is End of Life. Consider upgrading to a more recent version

Comment: Apparently some distributions of PHP screwed up some headers which mean a macro is missing. Imagick would work.....but yeah, you would be better off switching to a version of PHP that is still supported.

Comment: @Gordon, @Danack, thanks for your answers
i upgraded to php-5.4 and running the pecl install imagick command lead me to 

Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
ERROR: `phpize' failed

so, what i did was installing the package like this:

yum install php54w-pecl-imagick.x86_64

it seems to be there now,

[root@localhost src]# php -m | grep imagick
imagick

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. The possible solution is to install it from source following the steps:

```
cd /usr/local
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.3.0.tgz
tar zxvf ./imagick-3.3.0.tgz
cd imagick-3.3.0
phpize
./configure
make
make test
```

Then, you'll get the same error. To fix this, edit the file where the variable is undeclared:

```
vim /usr/local/imagick-3.3.0/imagick.c
```

to something like this:

```
3298 #endif
3299         // ZEND_MOD_END
3300         {NULL, NULL, NULL}
3301 };
3302 #endif
```

and try running again:

```
make test
make install
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since a (patched) php-5.3.3 is what comes with RHEL/CentOS 6 upgrading php is not always feasible. To build the imagick pecl module for CentOS 6 use version 3.1.2.

```
$ pecl install imagick-3.1.2
```